# Объединить метки [типы] и [types]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Кажется имеет смысл объединить метки [типы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%8b) и [types](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types). Заодно бы ещё и описание какое-то добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метки объединены в сторону русскоязычной.